# Service stops firing after while

Tags: android, service

I am using 
        `Intent i = new Intent(context, WakeWork.class);`
        `WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, i);`

Runs as expected for awhile...  Then, after an hour, it stops processing the 
`protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {`

It seems to not start the service within the WakeWork.class.  I have break points everywhere in the WakeWork.class and nothing is hitting breakpoints.  I can trace it up to the point the WakefulIntentService attempts to start service..   `ctxt.startService(i);`

It is an Alarm that fires every 60 seconds.  It starts the WakefulIntentService and does my work within the doWakefulWork sub.  There are no crashes, and no errors.  Nothing is shown in the LogCat.....   Again, works for a period of time, and then stops processing the doWakefulWork sub...

Anyone know what the heck is going on???

Comment: Every 60 seconds is on the frequent side for `AlarmManager` and `WakefulIntentService`. Double check `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to make sure your alarm is happening as you expect. Beyond that, I'd need a reproducible test case to help much more.

Comment: The Alarm is firing fine.  i can break point it at the Alarm `On Receive.`  Let me see what additional information i can get...

Comment: Sometimes it will run for a day, sometimes just an hour.  Is there any cleanup code that should occur for `doWakfulWork` that i should be doing? 
 
I have verified that the code is 100% reaching `sendWakefulWork` call.  But it never seems to fire `doWakefulWork`.  Where to troubleshoot from here?

Comment: "Is there any cleanup code that should occur for doWakfulWork that i should be doing?" -- no. "Where to troubleshoot from here?" -- I have no idea, sorry.